# How DB Manager works to fetch 50 row Oracle Database and implement it in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, odp.net

I want to implement how db manager (TOAD and OmniDB) used to fetch some row at the time of table data from oracle11g in C# (ODP.NET) and load it to DataTable, and use "Fetch More" to fetch another some row or "Fetch All" to fetch all row (it will take a long time)

I have read about OracleCommand.FetchSize or OracleDataAdapter.FetchSize, but still did'nt understand how to implement it

[image: Omni DB example]

Like picture above, omniDB only get first 50 records (while TOAD get 500 first records) it was fast in load, when I look on Oracle Session Browser, the query not manipulate to add "LIMIT" or "OFFSET" clause (how could this happen)

Comment: [You also might read the docs for FetchSize](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/odpnt/CommandFetchSize.html#GUID-4C26C1D4-DC67-4CAA-972D-FA3BF52DDBC6) to understand better what this does.

Comment: @JohnB add paging but not in query, I look on oracle session, the db manager just select normally (no script like limit, or rownum)

Comment: @BobJarvis still does'nt understand, would you give link or example how to implement it?